# How to remove Ambiguity in Context Free Grammar for NAND

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I am trying to construct a CFG for a boolean operator NAND..
This is what I have so far:

```
boolexp --> boolexp NAND boolexp
boolexp --> (boolexp)
boolexp --> True | False
```

The problem is when the input is something like "False NAND False NAND (True NAND True)"

This is clearly ambiguous, since there can be 2 different parse trees depending on the derivation.

How do I remove this ambiguity and redesign my CFG??

I want the NAND operator to be left-associative..
That is, if the input is A nand B nand C, I want it to be (A nand B) nand C

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
boolexp --> boolexp NAND boolterm
boolexp --> boolterm
boolterm --> (boolexp)
boolterm --> True | False
```

In case of `a NAND b NAND c` you get the only derivation

```
boolexp(a NAND b) NAND boolterm(c)
```

Comment: for the first line, do I also need,, boolexp --> boolexp NAND boolterm|boolterm ?

Comment: The grammar already has that.  Alternation `|` is just a shorthand for two productions as in the answer.

Comment: @ibid : I forgot it and added after comment as an edit.

Comment: Heh.  That's why I usually try to remember to note my edits based on comments as a reply comment.  Sorry for the noise :)